# Unable to check if variables are set

Tags: php

```
if(!isset($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) || isset($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) && $GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"] !== true)
{
    die("You need to run this function after <b>load_template</b>!");
}
```

This is my `add_template` function which adds more templates to the loaded one. `load_template` sets a value after adding the template (`$GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"] = true`) and I want to use add_template only if I run `load_template` first, but I always get

> You need to run...

even if I run `load_template`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
if(isset($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) && !empty($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]))
{
    echo 'You need to run this function after <b>load_template</b>!';die;
}
```

Comment: I don't if this will work. I want to send the error if $GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"] is not set, or if it is set, check if is true, else send the error.

Comment: Print your array, in question. you may use `if(isset($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) && empty($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]))` I dont know what exactly you want to do

Comment: as per your comment in above answer the condition will become `if(isset($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) && $GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"])` if this not work then hardcode true as ``if(isset($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) && $GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]===TRUE)``

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `!empty`. It is the best solution to check if the variable is declared and not empty.

> isset() checks if a variable has a
>   value including ( False , 0 , or empty
>   string) , but not NULL. Returns TRUE
>   if var exists; FALSE otherwise.
>
> On the other hand the empty() function
>   checks if the variable has an empty
>   value empty string , 0, NULL ,or
>   False. Returns FALSE if var has a
>   non-empty and non-zero value."

```
if (!empty($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) && ($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"] !== true)) {
    echo 'You need to run this function after <b>load_template</b>!';
    die;
}
```

Comment: I need to check if the value is set and is true.

Comment: oh you should have mentioned that.

Comment: Sorry for that. I saw something like `!(isset($GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) && $GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"]) === true` in some platforms, but doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Ok, wait. I ran `var_dump($GLOBALS);` and I see tpl_loaded is not set. Why? I set it inside function load_template() { ... }

Comment: It is obvious that it was not initialized. You can change your logic a little for that.

Comment: I found the problem. My `load_template` function was something like `require_once(required template);` and then $GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"], but my required file used `add_template`. I had to switch $GLOBALS["tpl_loaded"] with require_once, and now all good.

Comment: A pleasure to help. Sorry I was not unable to resolve this issue of yours.

Comment: I thought the issue was relating to unset and conditions.